# Trying to prevent memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, viewcontroller

I am trying to do some experiment.

```
- (IBAction)btn1Action:(id)sender {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"popvc2id" sender:self];
    });

    NSLog(@"TAP");
}
```

When button will tap it will take 1 second to perform segue and when this button tapped again it will trigger segue twice, so two instance of `ViewController` will be created.

In instruments I can see two instances but one of them is `leaked VC object`.

Now what I am trying to do is

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    VC2 *vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
    [ary addObject:vc2];
    if(ary.count > 1) {
        VC2 *vc = (VC2*)ary[1];
        vc = nil;
        [ary removeObjectAtIndex:1];
    }
    [ary removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@"-> %@", vc2);
}
```

to keep a record of `VC objects` and try to destroy the second obj, so I can prevent memory leak.

But its not working, how to I can fix it?

Comment: use bool FLAG to prevent second tap. Check flag before calling dispatch_after

Comment: so the issue is not performing the tap twice?

Comment: Setting a local variable to `nil`will **not** remove it from memory in general. You can't force iOS/ARC freeing an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cancel your previous request. My suggestion is using `NSObject CancelPreviousRequest` method

How to implement:

```
- (IBAction)btn1Action:(id)sender { 
   [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(delayedAction) object:nil];
   [self performSelector:@selector(delayedAction) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

-(void)delayedAction{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"popvc2id" sender:self];
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)btn1Action:(id)sender {
        __block UIButton * btn = (UIButton*) sender;

        btn.enabled = NO;

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"popvc2id" sender:self];
            btn.enabled = YES;
        });


        NSLog(@"TAP");
    }
```

Wrote  by memory, may be compile errors here

Comment: The user can still actually perform this double tap and make the segue perform action active.

Comment: @Joshua Did you removed this function? -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {...} You do not need any more